# WinRT App with API that uses shared MFC dlls

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-runtime

We have a C++ desktop application using an old MFC GUI; we would like to move it to a Windows App.
We use some sdk (for GigE cameras, CameraLink grabbers, vision libraries) that need msvcrt and shared mfc dlls. Including `<afx.h>` in a Windows App does not work.
Could be a solution packing everything in [WinRT components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155856.aspx) or there are simpler ones (or none at all, and we must stay within desktop apps)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFC cannot be used in a Windows Store app.  The only option is to eliminate use of MFC from the components that you would like to use in a Windows Store app.

Comment: Can msvcp110.dll, msvcr110.dll and msvcrt.dll be used?

Comment: msvcp110.dll and msvcr110.dll can be used, yes (you'll need to reference the VCLibs11 Framework Package).  msvcrt.dll cannot be used.